# Creating Data from Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read in a paper that the standard deviation is 0.41. This paper referred to a plot of another paper - now I ask myself, how to get the data? Is it possible to extract them from the plot?

Plese see the plot:

[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4zeX.png)

The standard deviation for the BT-5-6 curve should be 0.41 ... but there is no data in the paper, so it must be possible to extract it from the plot.

Comment: [This website](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) seems to extract data from plots. Apparently, it is [open source](https://github.com/ankitrohatgi/WebPlotDigitizer).

Comment: *there is no data in the paper, so it must be possible to* contact the authors and ask?